# Apache htaccess ErrorDocument directive not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found a vulnerability for content-spoofing on my webpage.

This URL:

https://www.mygreatsite.com/www.mygreatsite.com%20has%20moved%20to%20www.evilsite.com.%20CHECK%200UT%20H0W%20COOL%20THE%20NEW%20SITE%20IS!%20Sadly,%20the%20file%00

Apache Output:

**Not Found**

The requested URL /www.mygreatsite.com has moved to www.evilsite.com. CHECK 0UT H0W COOL THE NEW SITE IS! Sadly, the file was not found on this server.

--

The URL Overrides the Apache-Error and outputs the text added to the URL in the Browser, along with a 404-Error.

Actually, all requests to the server should be redirected to the CMS (Typo3) which in turn handles the 404-error and shows a custom page.
When I enter an URL that doesn't exist, this works perfectly. Just the above mentioned URL screws everything up.
Interestingly, when I delete the «`%00`» from the end of the URL, the request is forwarded to the CMS and the correct error document is displayed.

I tried to add a separate ErrorDocument-Directive to the htaccess-file - with no success.

Any ideas what goes wrong and how I could solve this?

As Anubhava points out, when a NULL-Byte is detected, Apache doesn't load any modules and just throws the 404. That's why `ErrorDocument` and mod_rewrite in the htaccess don't work.

[Edit for clarification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%00` or in Hex `\x00` is a NULL byte. When web server finds a NULL byte at the end then web server thinks it is a spoofing request and considers it to be dangerous to be processed by any directives.

Due to security reasons **web server doesn't load any modules for this request** and returns a 404 / `Not found` status. Browser shows default 404 page with your decoded URL just below **Not Found** text.

Comment: Not quite. At least Firefox sends the request to the browser. Chrome redirects to google.com, Safari just shows a blank page (as expected). Firefox also states that «The requested URL was not found on this server» - so I definitely assume, that the request was sent.

Comment: Well - that explains it - but doesn't solve my problem ;) When a spoofer enters malicious text in the URL (like my example above), the user sees that text on the Not-found-page and might be tempted to follow that link to the evil-site. So if Apache doesn't load any modules, that explains why mod_rewrite doesn't work. But I absolutely HAVE to provide a custom error page, even if there's this ominous NULL byte present... but how?

Comment: Apache just returns `404 (Not found)` immediately it detects URL is malicious. Even `ErrorDocument` won't be processed. But I don't understand link between maliciously entered URL and a genuine user seeing it. Response of a spoofed URL will only be noticed by spoofer.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't the case. When you enter the URL in FF, you'll see the text after the / in the URL will be added to the error-message, because Apache thinks that the text after the / is a path on the webserver. Thus, the user would be tempted to follow the link.

Comment: No you are misunderstanding it. You can turn on `Web Developer` tool in Firefox to see what's coming back from Apache. Apache just sends back `404` but browser adds current URL below **Not Found** heading for displaying a message to users.

Comment: @anubhava Is there any documentation about this behavior of Apache? Our sec team found this issue and the only thing I could dig up was this post.

Comment: @PalatinateJ: Sorry I don't recall any official documentation on this. This is based on the learning I observed doing my tests